# How to Run a For Loop excluding certain filenames in PuTTY Terminal (SSH connection)?

Tags: loops, for-loop, ssh, terminal, putty

In a SSH PuTTY connection, I have a directory with a bunch of files - I want to exclude some of these files in a FOR loop operation - Specifically, I want to exclude any files that have the words "Parrot" or "Tiger" in their filename - The below gives me the list of files I'm looking for.

```
ls Zoo_Animals*sas |grep -vi Parrot |grep -vi Tiger
```

For context, normally filenames would appear like *Zoo_Animals_Monkey_07.sas* or *Zoo_Animals_Lion_12.sas,* etc.

So, If I'd like to run a command for ALL animals, I'd normally Unixuse:

```
for file in Zoo_Animals*.sas; do <command here> "$file"; done
```

BUT, I can't seem to figure out how to run this FOR loop while excluding the files for Tigers and Parrots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Man find ,look at option -exec

Answer (score 0):

Embed your first command inside the second using `$()`

```
for f in $(ls Zoo_Animals*.sas |grep -vi Parrot |grep -vi Tiger); do echo $f; done
```